# Issue with background color change on nav-bar when hovered

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I'm trying to make the background color of my nav-bar change as the mouse hovers over it. I was able to do so with the 
CSS:

```
nav li a:hover {
  background-color:white;
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 205, 0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

But as I finished stylizing my nav-bar it stoped working for some reason. Any ideas why? PS: I'm very knew to coding (1 week in!) I will appreciate any feedback you have of any part of my code.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 205);
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 205);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 205, 0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#links">Social Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#actual-portfolio">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you want the whole navbar to change color? Currently `nav li a:hover` will make the links change color. If you want the navbar to change color try adding behaviour to `nav:hover`

Comment: It works just fine. The `rgba()` value is the same as your purple though, so you can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hover for li ..

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 205);
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 205);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 205, 0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#links">Social Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#actual-portfolio">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `background-color` declarations in

```css
nav li a:hover {
  background-color:white;
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 205, 0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

And the second one has the same `background-color` as your `ul { background-color }`, and it's the last one so the order of declaration picks it up.

I commented out the `rgba` one and it worked.

Something like this..

```css
nav li a:hover {
  background-color:white;
  //background-color: rgba(80, 80, 205, 0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

Hope this helps, [See this fiddle for visuals](https://jsfiddle.net/ujm38bcz/)

Welcome to coding!

Answer (score 0):

Change ur hover CSS as

```
nav li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(80, 80, 205);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

In your code

```
nav li a:hover {
  background-color: white; // First bg declaration
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 205, 0.3); // Second bg declaration
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

> background-color is given twice. So it takes the second one.

Remove that

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 205);
  border: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 205);
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 205);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(80, 80, 205);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#links">Social Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#actual-portfolio">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```